# laravel 5 image validation

Tags: php, laravel

I have an error here in my controller where I am trying to validate my image upload from my form post. It fails at the validator function. I know that my routes up to the controller works fine since if I uncomment the first line it works and sends back a json. Whats wrong with the validation. Im sort of new to laravel.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Storage;
use App\User as User;

class UserController extends Controller
{


    public function uploadProfileImg(Request $request){
        //return response()->json(['status'=>200,'request'=>$request->all()]);
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
             'file' => 'required|image|max:5500|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
         ]);
         return response()->json(['status'=>200]);

    }
}
```

Comment: It helps if you post error messages you get.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 public function uploadProfileImg(Request $request){
     //return response()->json(['status'=>200,'request'=>$request->all()]);
     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
         'file' => 'required|image|max:5500|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
     ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)
   }
   return response()->json(['status'=>200]);
```

in blade

```
@if(isset($errors))
    @if($errors->all())
        <ul style="list-style: none;" class="alert alert-warning">
            @foreach($errors->all() as $content)
                <li>{{$content}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif
@endif
```